# c# array merge without dupes. I cant use Linq and Lists

Tags: c#, arrays, merge

Let's say I have these two arrays:

```
string[] arr1 = new string[2]{"Hello", "Stack"}
string[] arr2 = new string[2]{"Stack", "Overflow"}
```

How would I merge them to get a third array like so:

```
string[3]{"Hello", "Stack", "Overflow"}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I mean, it is fobidden to use Linq and lists.

Comment: I understand that - what have you attempted so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Is [Hashset<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0#methods) allowed? If not, you will probably also need [Array.Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=net-5.0) if you can't use lists.

Comment: `Union` makes your life very easy, but We would like to know why you dont want to use linq?

Comment: @viveknuna it is for a uni project and it is fobidden.

Answer (score 3):

If order is unimportant, a hashset will work

```
var hs = new HashSet<string>(arr1);
hs.UnionWith(arr2);

var arr3 = new string[hs.Count];
hs.CopyTo(arr3);
```

If order is important, you can pair a hashset and a linked list; the hashset remembers things we saw before:

```
var hs = new HashSet<string>(arr1);
var ll = new LinkedList<string>(arr1);

foreach(var x in arr2)
  if(hs.Add(x))
    ll.Add(x);

var arr3 = new string[hs.Count];
ll.CopyTo(arr3);
```

A hashset's Add Method only returns true if the item was added - if we've already seen the item then it will not be added. This means if we only add to the LinkedList when we have successfully added to the HashSet then the LinkedList will end up with a unique set of elements in the original order as presented in the arrays. Note that this as presented *doesn't* dedupe the first array within itself. If the first array will have duplicates then instead of passing it to LinkedList's constructor, you should run two `foreach` loops i.e. process process both arrays like the second array is processed here

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's use `HashSet<string>` to check for duplicates ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KP9fYE)). The code below preserves the initial order:

```
{"Hello", "Stack"} + {"Stack", "Overflow"} ==
{"Hello", "Stack", "Stack", "Overflow"}    =>
{"Hello", "Stack", "Overflow"}
```

**Code:**

```
 // arr1.Length + arr2.Length is maximum possible length
 string[] result = new string[arr1.Length + arr2.Length];

 HashSet<string> unique = new HashSet<string>();

 for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length + arr2.Length; ++i) {
   // an item can be from arr1 or arr2
   string item = i < arr1.Length ? arr1[i] : arr2[i - arr1.Length];

   // if we have an unique item
   if (unique.Add(item))  
     result[unique.Count - 1] = item; // we put it to result at its place
 }

 // Since we may have got duplicates, we have to ajust result size
 Array.Resize(ref result, unique.Count);

 // Let's have a look at result
 Console.Write(string.Join(" ", result));
```

If `HashSet<T>` as well as any other collections (`List<T>`, `LinkedList<T>` etc.) are *forbidden* we can scan `result` to check duplicates:

**Array Only Code:**

```
 // arr1.Length + arr2.Length is maximum possible length
 string[] result = new string[arr1.Length + arr2.Length];

 int index = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length + arr2.Length; ++i) {
   // an item can be from arr1 or arr2
   string item = i < arr1.Length ? arr1[i] : arr2[i - arr1.Length];

   // Do we have an unique item?
   bool duplicate = false; 

   for (int j = 0; j < index; ++j)
     if (item == result[j]) {
       duplicate = true;

       break;
     }

   if (!duplicate) 
     result[index++] = item;
 }

 // Since we may have got duplicates, we have to ajust result size
 Array.Resize(ref result, index);

 // Let's have a look at result
 Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```